Как добавить репозиторий maven в проект
Я хочу добавить репозиторий maven в проект следующим образом:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
       maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}

Но получаю такую ошибку:

e: file:///C:/AndroidStudio/MyApplication4/build.gradle.kts:10:20: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Я ставил другой URL репозитория, и ставил точку с запятой в конце строки, ничего не помогало, оставалась та же ошибка.
Версия апи 34.
Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Версия АПИ не имеет ни малейшего значения к синтаксису Gradle скрипта: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

сделал Евгений, по инструкции, и вот ошибку выдает после того как ввел по инструкции:
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'

Try:


Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'
at


maven("https://maven.google.com") - только зачем, репозиторий гугла у вас и так задан через google()

Woess, оставил только googgle(), и сейчас такая огибка: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'

Try:


Run with --scan to get full insights.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle.kts'
at


https://stackoverflow.com/q/69163511/5479247

вообще убрал даже google()
и убрал все что выше писал и все заработало. ВИдимо лишнее , дивимо само добавлено уже в проект

В современном шаблоне студии репозитории объявлены в settings.gradle.kts с запретом на добавление в других местах.

точно!!! только сейчас это увидел
